# Animation doesn't render what I see in the preview!

Tags: rendering, animation, path, nla-editor

I'm working on a lego-animation. I've already set all keyframes and organized everything in the NLA-Editor.

When I scrub through the timeline everything works fine, but as soon as I press "render animation" my figure moves in a weird way.

Amazingly everything works fine, if I render individual frames out of the animation.

Here is my .blend file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiMEs6K4RudimRKMQZ0aUx4x9MQG

I really hope that somebody can help me!

Comment: Welcome, Nik135. Upload the .blend file using this internal link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's a good practice to render animation as sprites (images). You can render that images later to video using the Video Sequence Editor.

Comment: I found that the file you uploaded was wrong one, you were suppose to upload a .blend file instead of .blend1.